# How to update three.js BufferGeometry positions in Typescript

Tags: typescript, three.js

I'm trying to follow the recommended steps to update a BufferGeometry outlined in this document: https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-update-things

However I'm using typescript and when I try to change values on `line.geometry.attributes.position.array`like it's done on the example

```
    positions[ index ++ ] = x;
    positions[ index ++ ] = y;
    positions[ index ++ ] = z;
```

it throws an error `TS2542: Index signature in type 'ArrayLike<number>' only permits reading.`

Is there any other way of updating a BufferGeometry in run time?

Comment: Take a look at [`.setXYZ()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferAttribute.setXYZ) method of `THREE.BufferAttribute()`

Comment: If true that sounds like [a bug](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues)

Comment: also it has `count` property, if you are looping through index

Answer (score 2):

As prisioner849 said `BufferAttribute` has a [.setXYZ()](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferAttribute.setXYZ) method that should be used instead of directly updating positions at a certain index.